# How to query with Dates in Aggregate functions in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi, metabase

I'm using Metabase v0.41 and writing query to Cosmos DB as a mongoDb.

Metabase only allows execution of `db.collection.aggregate`, and I first want a match stage that does a basic string match and date range.
In SQL it'd be something like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE TABLE.COLUMN = 'WORD' AND TABLE.CREATEDAT > DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

and this is what I have for the equivalent mongo query.

So here are several attempts that I tried in the match query

1)

```json
    {
      $and: [
        {
          column: {$eq: "word" }
        },
        {
          
          createdAt:{$lt : //new ISODate()
            {
              $dateAdd:{
                  startDate: new ISODate(),
                  unit: "day",
                  amount: -1
              }
            } 
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

-> doesn't work even on mongo compass,this returns no results even if there are matching records in the database. but no syntax error either.

2. Subtract the difference in millisec

```json
        {
          $and: [
            {
                column: {$eq: "word" }
            },
           {
          
                createdAt:{$lt :new ISODate() -1231312321}
           }
          ]
        }
```

-> this does work on mongo compass, but not on Metabase.
the parser on the Metabase doesn't parse the number properly.

"JSON reader was expecting a name but found '-1231312321'."

3. I tried the subtraction using $subtract but still doesn't work.

Have any ideas?

Comment: `ISODate()` is an alias for `new Date()`, so use one of them but not `new ISODate()`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{ $expr: 
  { $lt: [
    "$createdAt", 
    {
      $dateSubtract:{
          startDate: "$$NOW",
          unit: "day",
          amount: 1
      }
    }] 
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I am starting to understand the issue thanks to your post. The thing is that neither $dateSubtract nor $expr is supported by Cosmos at this point 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/mongodb/feature-support-40

Haven't reached the conclusion, will update once I figure it out

Comment: Then try `{$subtract: ["$$NOW", 1000*60*60*24]}`

Comment: `$$NOW` is not in the supported system variables so it has to be `ISODate()`, and the parser on metabase doesn't support `*` s in that position, so that's also a no, which leaves us to `$match:{createdAt: {$lte: { $subtract:[ISODate(), 86400000]}}}`, which, surprisingly, doesn't return any documents and it's not the expected behaviour (should return some documents)   Mind blowing